# Linq Query for Tags/Fields

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to Linq and I have difficulties querying the database for a result containing multiple tag IDs.

So, I have two models:

Folders and FieldTags. The Folder holds a string with all FieldTag IDs listed in it. Example: 1,2,3

SopFolder Class:

```
public class SopFolder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string SopFields { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SopFolder> SopFolderChildrens { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SopBlock> Blocks { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SopReview> Reviews { get; set; }
    }
```

SopFields Class:

```
public class SopField
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to build a query which returns me a list of SopFolders which I can then output as a model (for binding in a view) and/or as json. Binding etc. is working fine, but only for the complete Folder list, not for the SopFields filtered result. Url for the action probably looks like this: /SopFolders/ShowTree/?id=4&SopFields=1,2,4

I am having Trouble constructing a query which delivers the SopFields filtered result.

Thanks for advice. I use asp.net mvc 4. Any Ideas on improving my whole approach is appreciated as well.

**UPDATE 1 (answer to comments):**

Bfore posting this example, I used an int collection for the SopFields but I replaced it with a string. It is quite easy to get values out of the string as well and it probably simplifies things a bit. Anyhow, it may also be an int collection. For me it is no difference.

The url I wrote was just to illustrate what arguments are passed to the action that delivers the results.

So I assume I have a List for the fieldTags instead of a string.

I am not very good in complex linq queries as I have to get my head into this but a conceptional query would look like this (it is not working, I am sure):

```
public ActionResult Index(List<int> fieldTags,int id = 1 )
{

// other stuff
 var model =
              _db.SopFolders
             .Where(r => r.Id == id && r.SopFields.Contains(sopFields))
             .Select(r => new
             {
                 id = r.Id,
                 Text = r.Name,
                 hasChildren = r.SopFolderChildrens.Any()
             });
// more stuff
 return View(model);
}
```

Regards,
Marcus

Comment: Why is SopFolder.SopFields property a string and not an int collection? Also 'Url for the action _probably_ looks like this' so you checked or you _think_ it is?

Comment: Please, explain your question with linq query

Comment: I updated the post above to provide information on your questions.